# ajax cannot pass data through post YII2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a normal form in the view. I'm not using an active form due to some circumstances that I'm using a jquery child window and the active form having conflicts in the appAsset.

```
<form id="technician-create-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" id="csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />                                           
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Technician No:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="technician_no" id="technician_no"  class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Code:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" name="tech_code" id="tech_code">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="tech_name" id="tech_name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-9">
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="addTechnicians" class="saveNew" name="addNewTechnicians">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

jquery

```
$(".saveNew").on("click",function(){
    //console.log("ok");
    var myBtn = this.name;
    switch (myBtn){
        case "addNewTechnicians":
            console.log(myBtn);
            var _csrf = $("#csrf").val();
            var technicianNo = $("#technician_no").val(),
                techCode = $("#tech_code").val(),
                techName = $("#tech_name").val(),

            $.ajax({
                url: 'technicians/create',
                type: 'post',
                data: 
                    {
                        _csrf : _csrf,
                        //_csrf : csrfToken,
                        technicianNo : technicianNo,
                        techCode : techCode,
                        techName : techName,

                    },
                //dataType: json,
                success: function(result){
                    var res = JSON.parse(result);
                    notificationMessage(res.technicians.notification,res.technicians.template);
                    if(res.technicians.template == "success"){
                        // $("#technician_no").val("");
                        // $("#tech_code").val("");
                    }

                },
                error: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("error in ajax form submission");
                    },
            });
     break;
 });
```

the Technicians controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

in the controller, I'm dumping the $_POST to check if the ajax was successfully passed on the controller but nothing happens. is this got to do with the csrf? because that's my problem awhile ago but now, this.

Comment: Have you looked in "network" logs of your browser? What kind of answer do you get?

Comment: @AntonF what do you mean by "network" logs? sorry, I'm just a newbie. are you talking about the console? I'm having a status: 200 and a readystate of 4. and a statusText of OK. I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: how do u trigger the ajax function ? Post it tooo

Comment: @SVinesh okay. I already post it now. can you check it. thank you!

Comment: have u consoled myBtn ? you get the value properly ? I think the right way is $(this).attr('name');

Comment: but I tried the console if the button was clicked and it was. I have `console.log(myBtn);` to check the button.

Comment: @SVinesh how would I do that? If I have too many forms on my page.

Comment: What can be wrong: 1. Wrong action. Your request gets passed to wrong action. 2. Some server error. See exactly what you're getting with server response.

Comment: no, I have correct action. I have been tweaking the code and now the $_POST can be seen in the console when I `print_r($_POST)` but not cannot be seen in technicians/create when I checked.

Answer (score 0):

There's your problem:

```
           type: 'get',
```

set it to

```
           type: 'post',
```

Comment: change $.ajax to $.post